# Возникли проблемы при вычислении суммы бесконечного ряда

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Написал код, согласно требованиям (задание приложу в скриншоте). Все вычисляет,ошибок не выдает, однако значение проверки суммы ряда отличается от значения самого ряда, то есть что-то из них я посчитал неверно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#define M_PI_4
using namespace std;

int fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * (n - 1);
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    double e = 10;
    e = pow(e, -4); // Заданная точность
    int n = 1;
    double x,
        m = 1,
        y = sqrt(2) / 2, //pi / 4 = sqrt(2)/2
        res = m;
    printf("Введите x (0.1 <= x <= 1): ");
    cin >> x;
    while (x > 1 || x < 0.1) {
        printf("Введено неверно значение x, попробуйте ещё раз (0.1 <= x <= 1): ");
        cin >> x;
    }
    while (m > e)
    {
        m *= cos(y)*x / fact(n);
        res += m;
        n++;
    }
    double check = exp(x * cos(y)) * cos(x * sin(y));
    cout << setprecision(5) << "Результат бесконечного ряда, в котором x = " << x << ": " << res << endl;
    cout << setprecision(5) << check << endl << res << " = " << check << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Значение pi/4 я записал в численном виде (√‎2/2), т.к. при вычислении синуса или косинуса из этого числа все время выдавало ошибку (я записывал ,к примеру, cos(M_PI_4) и выходила ошибка "Отсутствуют экземпляры. Перегруженная функция "cos", соответствующие списку аргументов").

Я все-таки думаю, что само вычисление бесконечного ряда у меня выполнено неверно, однако не могу понять, что я сделал не так)
[image: Само задание]
[image: Ошибка с cos]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `#define M_PI_4` —  ты зачем-то сам определил `M_PI_4`, отсюда и ошибка... также учти, что этот макрос не стандартный для языков Си и C++ (хотя он стандартен для POSIX), поэтому его может и не быть... в цикле тоже пара ошибок: незаметил `n` под косинусом в формуле, зачем-то берёшь уже вычисленное значение косинуса второй раз, неправильно пользуешься факториалом...

Comment: Так, а как тогда ввести pi/4, если я не введу его через #define, просто выдаст ошибку "идентификатор не определен". n-ку да, упустил в формуле...

Comment: Можно самому определить к корректному значению: `# define M_PI_4 0.78539816339744830962`; ещё это хорошо бы обернуть в `#ifdef`'ы... можно посмотреть документацию к своей libс — возможно она требует определения определённого макроса, чтобы определить математические константы `M_PI*`... можно, наконец, воспользоваться математикой: `# define M_PI_4 atan(1.0)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам не нужно считать факториал отдельно, не нужно задавать 10<sup>-4</sup> как `pow(10,-4)`, когда есть литерал `1e-4`, на худой конец `0.0001`, нужно считать `cos(n*pi/4)`, а не `cos(pi/4)`, нужно... много нужно. Все вместе дает вот такой код:

```
const double pi = 3.1415926;

double summa(double x, double eps = 1e-7) {
    double sum = 1, term = 1;

    for (int n = 1; abs(term) > eps; ++n)
        sum  = sum + (term *= x/n)*cos(n * pi / 4);

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    for (double x = 0.1; x < 1.05; x += 0.1) {
        cout
            << setprecision(3) << left << setw(4) << x
            << setprecision(7) << left << setw(10) << summa(x)
            << setprecision(7) << left << setw(10)
            << exp(x * cos(pi / 4))*cos(x * sin(pi / 4)) << endl;
    }
}
```

Кстати, вычисление `cos(n*pi/4)` действительно можно ускорить (но не упростить), примерно как

```
double NCos(int n)
{
    static const double s2 = 1/sqrt(2);
    double res = (n%2 == 1) ? s2 : (n%4 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    if (n%8 >= 3 && n%8 <= 5) res *= -1;
    return res;
}
```

(http://ideone.com/Ty4E3h)

Comment: Так у вас по итогу 2 значения все равно разными получаются, хотя они должны быть равны (2 формула для проверки дана).

Comment: Значит, ошибся в `NCos`, сейчас исправлю. С `cos` все верно - http://ideone.com/Otn0Ts Да, нашел - просто вместо `1 : 0` написал `0:1`.

Comment: ИМХО `NCos` будет куда проще выглядеть, если использовать `switch()`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer На любителя, на любителя... :)

Comment: А для чего вы eps вводили, можете объяснить? Просто не совсем понял

Comment: Погрешность при вычислении ("*с заданной точностью*").